# Laravel sort two foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, function, sorting

I have two foreach loops:

```
@foreach($masseurs as $masseur)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $masseur->name }}</td>             
      <td>{{ $masseur->visa_expire }}</td>  
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

```
@foreach($masseurs as $masseur)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $masseur->name }}</td>             
      <td>{{ $masseur->passsport_expire }}</td>  
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

I would like to sort the results of the two loops with `sortBy`, so I assume that I need to combine them. How to do that?

Comment: What are you sorting by? You're iterating through the same collection on both loops, so you can inline it if you want, or sort beforehand.

Comment: If you want to sort, why not sort by SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

In Controller:

```
$masseurs->sortBy('visa_expire');
```

In view:

```
@foreach($masseurs as $masseur)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $masseur->name }}</td>             
      <td>{{ $masseur->visa_expire }}</td>
      <td>{{ $masseur->passsport_expire }}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```